# Setup an app to detect OS ver. and iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

1. How can I detect whether my app is running on an iPhone or iPad, and what iOS version it is running?
2. Can I use pre-processor macros in a similar fashion to `#if _OS4.0` or `#if IPAD` or something of the sort?
3. Is this kosher, or should I just make separate builds for submission?

Answer (score 2):

Generally using features based on OS version is bad practice.

As offered, use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() whenever possible.  Also use:

```
Class qlPreview = NSClassFromString(@"QLPreviewController");
```

and

```
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
if([mainScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]){
     NSLog(@"screen scale: %f",[mainScreen scale]);
}
```

However, sometimes you can't avoid it checking for system version.

Comment: Note that `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and `addGestureRecognizer:` exist even before 3.2 — they are just being private.

Comment: Right, bad example :)  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() can be used to detect the device.
Possible return values are:

- UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone
- UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

`if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {}`

There's also the `__IPHONE_3_2` define that can help:

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_3_2
    /* ... */
#elif
   /* ... */
#endif
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. I've run into some other issues though. When I try to build with my iPad target, all of the code for my iAd stuff breaks.